# Dfference between emulator and AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have just switch to android development and came across this doubt. How is **AVD** different from **emulator**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**AVD : Android Virtual Device**

Quoting from the Android Developer Site : [Managing Virtual Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html)

> An Android Virtual Device (AVD) is an emulator configuration that lets
>   you model an actual device by defining hardware and software options
>   to be emulated by the Android Emulator.

This itself means `AVD` and `emulator` are different. ie, `AVD` is an `emulator configuration`. Again, `AVD` is a configuration that runs on `Android Emulator`

**Android Emulator**

Now we need a explanation for `Android Emulator`. Again quoting from developer site. [Using the Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

> The Android SDK includes a virtual mobile device emulator that runs on
>   your computer. The emulator lets you prototype, develop and test
>   Android applications without using a physical device.
>
> The Android emulator mimics all of the hardware and software features
>   of a typical mobile device, except that it cannot place actual phone
>   calls. It provides a variety of navigation and control keys, which you
>   can "press" using your mouse or keyboard to generate events for your
>   application. It also provides a screen in which your application is
>   displayed, together with any other active Android applications.
>
> **To let you model and test your application more easily, the emulator
>   utilizes Android Virtual Device (AVD) configurations.** AVDs let you
>   define certain hardware aspects of your emulated phone and allow you
>   to create many configurations to test many Android platforms and
>   hardware permutations. Once your application is running on the
>   emulator, it can use the services of the Android platform to invoke
>   other applications, access the network, play audio and video, store
>   and retrieve data, notify the user, and render graphical transitions
>   and themes.

Note the **BOLD** sentence in above quote. It clearly mentions that, ***Android Emulator utilizes AVD configurations***.

Answer (score 6):

An Android Virtual Device (AVD) is an emulator configuration that lets you model an actual device by defining hardware and software options to be emulated by the Android Emulator.

Answer (score 6):

An **Android Virtual Device (AVD) is an emulator** configuration that lets you model an actual device by defining hardware and software options to be emulated by the Android Emulator.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html

The Android SDK includes a mobile device emulator — a **virtual mobile device** that runs on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

**AVD** :Android Virtual device is an emulator which gives you a platform to test your apps,and see how it will look on real devices.

You can set up configuration from AVD Manager for Emulators, and see behaviour of your application on different OS versions, screen sizes and many more.

Answer (score -1):

AVD is Android Virtual Device which is the same as Android Emulator. They mean the same